# Unable to insert text with soft return \v characters

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

When insert text via office.js (Word Online) with the insertText command the soft return character (char 11) is rendered as a square instead of a proper line-break.

I've tried char(11).  \r and \n produce paragraph breaks.  Whereas I want a line-break so that it doesn't increment the numbering of a bullet list

```
text = 'This is a\vline break test';
Word.run(context => {
    context.document.getSelection().insertText(text, Word.InsertLocation.end);
    return context.sync();
});
```

A \v should be rendered the same as if an end-user has typed SHIFT+ENTER.  Instead it's just rendering the square character

Comment: I cannot reproduce this using the [Script Lab](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/wa104380862) tool. Your code works and the `\v` produces a line break and no square. Try running it in Script Lab to see what happens.

Comment: I am curious too. Can't produce the soft return with this neither: [JavaScript String fromCharCode() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromcharcode.asp)

Answer (score 1):

This approach works for me.  Might help someone else

```
const lines = text.split('\n');
const { Word } = window;
Word.run(context => {
    for (let i = lines.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        let line = lines[i];
        context.document.getSelection().insertText(line, Word.InsertLocation.end);

        if (i !== 0) {
            context.document.getSelection().insertBreak(Word.BreakType.line, 'After');
        }
    }

    return context.sync();
});
```